# Getting 401 error in Joomla backend when trying to login\logout or edit anything

Tags: joomla, administrator

I have a website built on Joomla.Everything seemed to be going fine when all of a sudden I am noticing the following.
When I go to the administrator login page, once I fill my details and press login, I am getting a 401.shtml page with following message - 
"Not Found

The requested URL /401.shtml was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 mod_perl/2.0.5 Perl/v5.8.8 Server at www.shillingstudios.com Port 80"

Now as per my understanding the 401 error would mean that I do not have the authorization to visit that page or do what I am trying to do.Maybe I am not entering the correct username or password.
However,my username and password are correct.Moreover if I go back to the admin login page I find that I am logged into the administrator panel, which means that my login attempt was successful even though I was directed to 401.shtml page.
The same thing happens when I try to logout(on refresh I find that I had successfully logged out)
When I try to Save/Edit/Close an Article/Category/Section I am redirected to the same page.But in each instance I am actually able to successfully do what I was trying to do.

The only change that I made prior to this issue was installing following plug-ins:

Set Generator tag plug-in

Title Manager plug-in

I installed both plug-ins for SEO purpose from http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/seo-a-metadata

I thought that the issue might have caused due to installing these plug-ins so I disabled them, but the problem is still there.

I am trying to setup a website for an Android game that I am developing and Joomla seemed a good option for creating my own website. However I do not have much idea about PHP or MySQL or how Apache server works.So I am not able to determine why this is happening and what can possibly fix this, so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try making sure that your website URL is in the 'live site' field in the config.php file. That can sometimes help.

Comment: Hi Peter, My website URL is already present in the "live site" field in the config.php file.I think the issue is something else.

Comment: Accepting Peter's answer because this is the first thing you should be doing, updating the 'live site' field. However, this was already in place for me. Luckily my site was new so I just reinstalled Joomla and this worked for me. If you are doing a regular backup of your website this should work but I guess there could have been a simpler/better solution.

Answer (score 0):

First you should create your custom error pages – you can use a text/HTML editor of your choice (for example Dreamweaver). Once you are ready with the pages, upload them into a subdirectory of your public_html called errors. Then open your main .htaccess file and add the following lines in it:

## serve custom error pages

ErrorDocument 400 /errors/400.html

ErrorDocument 401 /errors/401.html

ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.html

ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html

ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.html

Answer (score 0):

Important settings:

- Search Engine Friendly URLs: `Yes`
- Use Apache mod_rewrite: `Yes`
- `Mod_login` settings: *All defaults from installation*

**edit:**

I did rename `htaccess.txt` into `.htaccess`